# Cannot resolve classes of src project from within submodules

Tags: java, android-studio

I got a really strange behavior after upgrading Android studio version to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Basically, s**ome modules of my project are no longer able to recognize the main source code classes that are referenced on AndroidTest** (instrumentation) nor **Test**(unitTest) submodules.

However, **nothing has been modified from my project**, moreover,when building and running the apk from the IDE ,it builds ok, so it seems it’s only impacting test modules.
Some forums suggested try invalidating the IDE system cache but the problem is still present

**Does someone get an insight or similar situation and how to solve it?**

the build.gradle file hasn't change neither

[image]

build seems ok
[image]

Comment: Does build fail? or just runtime Android Studio issue? If that's the case just do an invaldate + restart.

Comment: yes ,Build succeed but when referencing test modules it seems android doesn't see the packages from main source code

Comment: Doesn't the invalidate + restart solve the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no